# Is there protection against NoSQL injections in the official MongoDB driver for .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, nosql-injection

Does the official MongoDb driver for .NET have protection against NoSQL injections? It would be great to get a link to part of the repository with the code or logic that provides this protection (if there is protection).

Answer (score 0):

Not specific to the .NEt driver, but this is apparenlty not problematic unless you are building JavaScript queries manually

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/fundamentals/#javascript

BSON queries will simply fail:

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/faq/fundamentals/#how-does-mongodb-address-sql-or-query-injection-